# How to check if a price range is included in any price range with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, range

I would like to insert a new price range in a table but before I need to check if my price range is already included or part of any other price range.

Here is an example:

My price range table:

```
| minimum | maximum |
---------------------
|       1 |     100 |
|     201 |     300 |
|     301 |     400 |
```

- If I submit [50,200], I must reject it because 50 is included in the range [1,100].
- If I submit [175,201], I must reject it because 201 is included in the range [201,300].
- If I submit [350,380], I must reject it because 350 and 380 are included in the range [301,400].
- If I submit [120,190], I must **accept** it because 120 and 190 are not included in any range.

My question is how to check with MySQL if the submitted range is included or not in my table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (assuming the table is called `ranges` and the new range parameters are @low and @high respectively):

```
IF(NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM ranges
                WHERE @low BETWEEN minimum AND maximum)
   AND 
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM ranges
                WHERE @high BETWEEN minimum AND maximum))
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO ranges
         (minumum, maximum)
       VALUES
         (@low, @high)
END
```

Of course, this could be further coalesced/condensed:

```
IF(NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM ranges
                WHERE @low BETWEEN minimum AND maximum
                   OR @high BETWEEN minimum AND maximum))
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO ranges
         (minumum, maximum)
       VALUES
         (@low, @high)
END
```

And even further:

```
INSERT INTO ranges
   (minimum, maximum)
SELECT T.minimum, T.maximum
  FROM (SELECT @low as minimum, @high as maximum) T
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                     FROM ranges
                    WHERE @low BETWEEN minimum AND maximum
                       OR @high BETWEEN minimum AND maximum)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO priceranges 
  SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT <newminprice>, <newmaxprice>) AS baseview 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM ranges 
    WHERE <newminprice> BETWEEN minimum AND maximum
      OR <newmaxprice> BETWEEN minimum AND maximum
  )
```

should do it in one query

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your new values to test are `rangestart, rangeend`, select a row having either the start or end between `minimum AND maximum`.  Any resultant row will indicate that the range overlaps and cannot be added.  If this query returns no rows, the range does not overlap and is valid.

```
SELECT 
  TRUE
FROM ranges
WHERE
   rangestart BETWEEN minimum AND maximum
   OR rangeend BETWEEN minimum AND maximum
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT 'True' as Result
  FROM PriceRange
 WHERE iStartValue BETWEEN minimum AND maximum OR
       iEndValue   BETWEEN minimum AND maximum
```